# Detect CRC version starting from input and results

Tags: python, crc

I have a sample of a 6-byte code and his CRC result and I need to write a little CRC function in Python that calculates it starting from an arbitrary 6-byte input but I don't know what version of CRC I need.

This is the input:

```
0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01 0xFF 0xFF
```

...and this is the result:

```
0xC2 0x00
```

Someone know what version of CRC is used?
I have already tried using crcmod but the result is always different.

I also have a snippet of the function written in C if can help:

```
ShiftRegister = 0xFFFF;
Pchar = (&Buffer[0]);
for (p=0;p<ReceivedBytes;p++)
{
    dato = (*Pchar)*256;
    Pchar++;
    for (i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
        if((ShiftRegister ^ dato)& 0x8000)
        {
            ShiftRegister <<=1;
            ShiftRegister ^= 0x8005;
        }
        else
        {
            ShiftRegister <<=1;
        }
        dato <<= 1;
    }
}
```

where `&Buffer[0]` is the pointer to the input and `ReceivedBytes` is the length.

Comment: You need to provide several more examples to even have a hope of reverse-engineering the CRC.  Do you know how many bits the CRC is?  How do you know it _is_ a CRC?

Comment: Thanks Mark, unfortunately I have only this example, but I have a added a snippet of the function written in C if can help

Comment: Why were you asking what CRC is being used _when you have the source code_?!  That is exactly what is being used.  You should have provided the source code in the first place.  It is straightforward to convert that to python.  Just make sure you `& 0xffff` at the end.

Comment: Solved, the problem was the missing `& 0xffff`, again thanks